# How to include SIGAR API in Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, sigar

I'm new on Java, so i don't know who to get the downloading zip-file (hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip) in the project where i've to use the Sigar-classes.

I already try to import the Sigar.Jar file, but the problem is then that the sources are unknown for each class in sigar.

So i use Eclipse Indigo for programming, may someone can help me :)

Very Thanksfull greets

Marcus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First You need to add `Sigar.jar` to your library, then add `.so` file to your library (you need to pick file for your OS what you are using). You can find these files in `"hyperic-sigar-1.6.4/sigar-bin/lib"`. You can find the usage of `Mem` function in the example code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;


import org.hyperic.sigar.Mem;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

public class MemExample {

    private static Sigar sigar = new Sigar();

    public static void getInformationsAboutMemory() {
        System.out.println("**************************************");
        System.out.println("*** Informations about the Memory: ***");
        System.out.println("**************************************\n");

        Mem mem = null;
        try {
            mem = sigar.getMem();
        } catch (SigarException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Actual total free system memory: "
                + mem.getActualFree() / 1024 / 1024+ " MB");
        System.out.println("Actual total used system memory: "
                + mem.getActualUsed() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");
        System.out.println("Total free system memory ......: " + mem.getFree()
                / 1024 / 1024+ " MB");
        System.out.println("System Random Access Memory....: " + mem.getRam()
                + " MB");
        System.out.println("Total system memory............: " + mem.getTotal()
                / 1024 / 1024+ " MB");
        System.out.println("Total used system memory.......: " + mem.getUsed()
                / 1024 / 1024+ " MB");

        System.out.println("\n**************************************\n");


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

                getInformationsAboutMemory();

                }

}
```

Comment: So i add the sigar.jar file to my JRE System Library and i copying all .so files from hyperic-sigar-1.6.4/sigar-bin/lib to Java/jre6/lib But now i always get the message:
<pre>
Failed to load sigar-amd64-winnt: java.lang.NullPointerException org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: Failed to load sigar-amd64-winnt: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:170) at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.<clinit>(Sigar.java:100) at MemExample.<clinit>(MemExample.java:14) 
<code>
so what's wrong?

Comment: Also add this file sigar-x86-winnt.lib to your library.

Comment: I'm using Win 7, 64 Bit, so whats the sence of using the 32Bit lib?
But i tried and the result is the same. May is it possible that the sigar-function get bugs. But i didn't get a look in the classes, so i'm at a loss.

Comment: i add the complete sigar library to my jre6/lib so it shouldn't care using the jre6/lib (with the sigar files) or the sigar file.

Comment: In my case i am using Ubuntu(64 bit), I placed sigar.jar & libsigar-x86-linux.so in my projects lib folder (i.e /home/project/Metrics/lib/) it works fine for me...

Comment: hm. may the win file is defect, is it possible?
Otherwise i didnt found anything in the hyperic-sigar-forum about this problem, only for the version 1.6.0.

Answer (score 3):

The downloaded zip will contain a folder or two giving examples in how to use some of the functions. Example of the folder can be found at:

"hyperic-sigar-1.6.4/bindings/java/examples"