# Detect CPU model information

Tags: java, linux, unix, cpu, hardware

Is there a way to get info about cpu model (for unix system) in Java? I mean without using system commands like `cat /proc/cpuinfo`.

I want get something like: "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz"

Thanks!

Comment: Reading this file is the simplest way to do this.

Comment: You can possibly use [JNI](https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/java-native-interface-jni-example-65) but why?

Comment: Yous don't have to *(...) using system commands like `cat /proc/cpuinfo`*. You may   want to open `/proc/cpuinfo` just like any other file and read it until you get a line beginning with `model name`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is a duplicata for this one [get OS-level system information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information), however I'll re-post the best answer for that one.

> You can get some limited memory information from the Runtime class. It
>   really isn't exactly what you are looking for, but I thought I would
>   provide it for the sake of completeness. Here is a small example. You
>   can also get disk usage information from the java.io.File class. The
>   disk space usage stuff requires Java 1.6 or higher.
>
> ```
> public class Main {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>     /* Total number of processors or cores available to the JVM */
>     System.out.println("Available processors (cores): " + 
>         Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
>
>     /* Total amount of free memory available to the JVM */
>     System.out.println("Free memory (bytes): " + 
>         Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
>
>     /* This will return Long.MAX_VALUE if there is no preset limit */
>     long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
>     /* Maximum amount of memory the JVM will attempt to use */
>     System.out.println("Maximum memory (bytes): " + 
>         (maxMemory == Long.MAX_VALUE ? "no limit" : maxMemory));
>
>     /* Total memory currently available to the JVM */
>     System.out.println("Total memory available to JVM (bytes): " + 
>         Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
>
>     /* Get a list of all filesystem roots on this system */
>     File[] roots = File.listRoots();
>
>     /* For each filesystem root, print some info */
>     for (File root : roots) {
>       System.out.println("File system root: " + root.getAbsolutePath());
>       System.out.println("Total space (bytes): " + root.getTotalSpace());
>       System.out.println("Free space (bytes): " + root.getFreeSpace());
>       System.out.println("Usable space (bytes): " + root.getUsableSpace());
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

In your case you want the `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`.

There is another way, using sigar API. For that you need to download sigar from [this link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/files/), and check this to include it in your project [How to include SIGAR API in Java Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214114/how-to-include-sigar-api-in-java-project).

You will then use something like this:

```
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
import org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException;

public class CpuInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SigarException {
        Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
        org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo[] cpuInfoList = sigar.getCpuInfoList();
        for(org.hyperic.sigar.CpuInfo info : cpuInfoList){
            System.out.println("CPU Model : " + info.getModel());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply read `/proc/cpuinfo`.

```
String model = Files.lines(Paths.get("/proc/cpuinfo"))
   .filter(line -> line.startsWith("model name"))
   .map(line -> line.replaceAll(".*: ", ""))
   .findFirst().orElse("")
```

Comment: Orange PIs (and possibly other PIs as well) don't have `model name`. They list what looks like the model name under `Processor` (with capital P): https://pastebin.com/FNJqgy29

Answer (score 0):

If you want that level of detail, your best bet is to read the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` and parse out the part you want.

Otherwise, from within a JVM, you can get a count of the [number of processor cores](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors())

```
int count = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

or [OS architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getArch()):

```
String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems [Sigar](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar) mentioned in another answer is no longer maintained and does not work with recent Windows versions because of 64b/32b incompatibilites (see [PR 142](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/pull/142)).

There seems to be another library for the purposes, which seems to be alive (last version published a few days ago) [OSHI](https://github.com/oshi/oshi).

With OSHI you can get the information like this:

```
SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();
HardwareAbstractionLayer hal = si.getHardware();
CentralProcessor cpu = hal.getProcessor();
String name = cpu.getProcessorIdentifier().getName();
```