# Java - Need to Conditionally enable a Unit test dependent on whether the device is a Mac M1

Tags: java, apple-m1

I need to enable a test whenever the system running the test is not an m1 mac.

Struggling to find a way to identify when the device is an m1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect apple silicon (M1) vs. intel in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74315665/how-do-i-detect-apple-silicon-m1-vs-intel-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java you can get informations about the system running the JVM using the following:

```
 //Operating system name
 System.out.println("Your OS name -> " + System.getProperty("os.name"));

 //Operating system version
 System.out.println("Your OS version -> " + System.getProperty("os.version"));

 //Operating system architecture
 System.out.println("Your OS Architecture -> " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
```

So you should build your logics around the last method, the returned values are Strings.

On your M1 Mac you should get an output like this:

```
Your OS Architecture -> aarch64
```

Comment: To be precise, an M2 Mac will also give that response, not just M1.

Comment: Any Apple Silicon device will give that output, since it's the architecture of the system (ARM).